# Add CSS Avada responsive mobile

Tags: php, html, css

I'm using Avada for my website and I'd like to change the way responsive works on a single page. I'm using a lot of images for a color chart : https://couleurbeton.fr/nuancier-ad-lucem/
On mobile display (small screens) it only displays 1 image per line (one at a time). With 90 colors to display that's quite a lot to scroll through. I wanted like 3-5 per line more like this : http://www.adlucem-matieres.com/beton-cire/couleurs/notre-palette/ (have to watch on small display)
It might have to do with classes like this but I'm no expert at all. Any advice is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

```html
<div class="fusion-fullwidth fullwidth-box nonhundred-percent-fullwidth">
<div  class="fusion-layout-column fusion_builder_column fusion_builder_column_1_2  fusion-one-half fusion-column-first 1_2"  style='margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:0px;width:50%;width:calc(50% - ( ( 4% ) * 0.5 ) );margin-right: 4%;'
<div class="fusion-column-wrapper" style="background-position:left top;background-repeat:no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:cover;-moz-background-size:cover;-o-background-size:cover;background-size:cover;"  data-bg-url="">
<div class="fusion-builder-row fusion-builder-row-inner fusion-row ">
<div  class="fusion-layout-column fusion_builder_column fusion_builder_column_1_5  fusion-one-fifth fusion-column-first fusion-one-fifth fusion-column-first 1_5"  style='margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;width:20%;width:calc(20% - ( ( 4% + 4% + 4% + 4% ) * 0.2 ) );margin-right:4%;'>
<div class="fusion-column-wrapper" style="background-position:left top;background-repeat:no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:cover;-moz-background-size:cover;-o-background-size:cover;background-size:cover;"  data-bg-url="">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to add this code :

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {    
.fusion-body .fusion-layout-column.fusion_builder_column_1_5 {
     width: 32% !important;
}
}
```